# delete a row from the database using an id button laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have a database table with 2 components , id and body , the body is a text, as i specified in the laravel database migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->text('body');
```

i created a file controller todocontroller --resource with the following commande with my terminal `php artisan make:controller todoController --resource` , i got a lot of functions : between them 3 that have relations with the id :

```
public function show($id)
    {
      return $id ;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      DB::table('todos')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
   return view('pages.home');;
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
```

i want to delete the row that i like from a simple click button that i created it in the Home.blade.php :

```
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($todos as $todo)
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <form action="" method="">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >{{$todo->id}}</button>
</form>
  </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

i tried to get a lot of times the root from the terminal using `php artisan route:list` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See below link and if you don't get anything tell me I will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4/44114038

Answer (score 0):

for delete in resource route you can write a new route

```
Route::get('/todo/delete/{id},'todoController@destroy')->name('todo.destroy');


<ul class="list-group">
@foreach($todos as $todo)
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align- 
 items-center">
  <form action="" method="">


  <a href="{{route('todo.destroy',$todo->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >Delete</button></a
 </form>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

```
public function destroy($id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $todo= Todo::find($id);
    $todo->delete();
    return redirect()->route('homepage');
}
```

in view:

```
@foreach(...)
    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['todos.destroy', $todo->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('DELETE') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 5.6 this is simple, just to use the code below to delete one row of your database base on the id of row:

1- first in web.php define name for delete method of controller we need this to call in blade form

`Route::delete('todos/{todo}', 'TodoController@destroy')->name('todos.delete');`

2- in blade file just create form like below (just replace it to your form in foreach loop)

`<form method="post" action={{ route('todos.delete') , ['id' => $todo->id] }}>
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="hidden" value="DELETE"/>
<button type="submit">click to delete this row base on id</button>`

3- and last in destroy method of your controller

`$todo = Todo::whereId($id);
$todo->delete();
return back();`

hope to work for you friend:)