# How to delete data from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, frameworks

In my website, I have a page where users can see their orders. In this table, I want to be able to delete the order by clicking a link. However, everything i tried so far isn't working. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to make I work. It keeps giving me a 404 error.

My Route:

```
Route::get('destroy/{$id}', 'AccountController@destroy');
```

My Controller function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    RestaurantModel::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return back('/');
}
```

My Model: Don't mind the model name.

```
class RestaurantModel extends Model
{
protected $table = 'orders';
protected $primarykey = 'orderNumber';
}
```

The row from the table in my view: The delete function is at the back of the code.

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
            <tr>
                 <td><a href="">{{{ $order->orderNumber }}}</a></td>
                 <td>{{{ $order->orderDate }}}</td><td>{{{ $order->shippedDate }}}</td>
                 <td>{{{ $order->status }}}</td>
                 <td>{{{ $order->comments }}}</td>
                 <td>{{{ $order->customerNumber }}}</td>
                 <td><a href="{{ action('AccountController@destroy', $order->orderNumber) }}">Delete order</a></td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

I hope someone can help me with my problem. I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: did you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did, however, its still giving me a 404 error.

Comment: please refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4

Comment: Please share the URL for 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your route

```
Route::get('destroy/{$id}', 'AccountController@destroy');
```

to

```
Route::get('destroy/{id}', 'AccountController@destroy');
```

Comment: It's still giving me a 404 not found error. I assume the problem is my route?

Comment: Changed answer to what I think might be the problem, could you try and post results?

Comment: I tried changing my route to the route you provided for me. It deleted the row from the database, but its still throwing errors. This is the error it gave me. Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, string given, called in D:\wamp64\www\restaurant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203

Comment: Thats good! It's now getting in the method. However, there's still an error then.

Change your ```return back('/');``` to either ```return redirect()->back();``` or ```return redirect('/);```.

```redirect()->back();``` redirects the user to the previous page, and ```redirect('/');``` redirects the user to the '/' endpoint.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much for your help, you're a hero!