# how to delete user from return in controller

Tags: html, laravel

route not working, where should I put `@csrf` and `@method('DELETE')`? because it does not delete the user. before the problem happens, `@csrf` and `@method('DELETE')` was in blade view. But when I put `@csrf` and `@method('DELETE')` in return it shows an error.

```
$employees = DB::table('users')->leftjoin('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')->leftjoin('supervisors', 'users.manager_id', '=', 'supervisors.id')
                ->select(['users.id','users.name','users.department','users.email','users.leaves_available','roles.name_role','supervisors.name_supervisor']);
                return Datatables::of($employees)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($employees) {

            return '<form action="'.route('employee.destroy', $employees->id).'" method="post">
                                <button type:"submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        })->make(true);
```

in the form I use route('employee.destroy', $employee->id) then the parameter will be http://localhost:8000/employee/1 and I want the user got delete.

EmployeeController.php

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete($id); 
        return redirect()->route('home')
                        ->with('success','Employee have been deleted');
    }
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('employee/{id}', 'EmployeeController@destroy');
```

I expect the destroy function will run and redirect back to home. But what I get is :

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use DELETE method in route with Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4)

Comment: The error message says part of it. You're sending a `POST` request to a route defined with `Route::get()`.

Comment: @SalmanZafar i use the input hidden with csrf and method delete and it worked.

Comment: @newUserName02 i change the route to post and it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the route from get to post. Like this

`Route::post('employee/{id}', 'EmployeeController@destroy');`

Because, you are using `post` method in your form but your `route` is in get. Both need to be same.