# Axios - receiving a 404 error when trying to delete user from database

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

so I'm currently trying to delete a user from a mySql database on clicking a delete button. The app is Laravel backend, React front end.

When I click the delete button, it returns a 404 error 'DELETE http://localhost:8000/delete/5 404 (Not Found)'

onDelete method:

```
onDelete(user_id) {

        axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/users/delete/' + user_id)
            .then((response) => {

            })
    }
```

UserController

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->delete();
    }
```

Button in code:

```
<button onClick={this.onDelete.bind(this, Users.id)}>Delete</button>`
```

Web Route:

```
Route::delete('users/delete/{id}', 'Api\UserController@destroy');
```

The error contains the correct id (the last number in the error code url is the correct id of the user I'm trying to delete) but I've got no idea why it's giving me a 404 error.

*Update* Turns out the delete route isn't in my route list. (php artisan route:list)

```
Route::get('userList', 'Api\UserController@index'); 
Route::post('users/store', 'Api\UserController@store'); 
Route::delete('users/delete/{id}', 'Api\UserController@destroy');
```

Strange because the get and post routes are in the route list, but not my delete route. (The above code is in my web.php file) All three methods (index, store and destroy) are inside my UserController controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $result = User::all();
        return $result;
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->user_name;
        $user->email = $request->user_email;
        $user->phone_number = $request->user_phoneNumber;
        $user->account_type = $request->user_accType;
        $user->qualifications = $request->user_qualifications;
        $user->save();
    }

public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->delete();
    }
```

Comment: Use get method `Route::get('users/delete/{id}', 'Api\UserController@destroy');`

Comment: This question might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4

Comment: If your Laravel is in local development mode, it should give you more than 404. Check your logs for details. Are you sure that route is in the correct group and everything? The above comments are suggesting you have the wrong method, but this would give you "405 Method not Allowed" error. Check `artisan route:list` to make sure it's there with the expected URL.

Comment: @miken32 you got it, the delete method isn't in my route list. I'm really new to all this, how do I put it in there? Thanks so much

Comment: It should be in `routes/web.php`

Comment: @miken32 apologies, now amended.

Comment: That's your entire route file?

Comment: You can also try `php artisan cache:clear` to make sure your routes aren't cached.

Comment: @miken32 tried everything, the eventual fix was the 'php artisan route:clear' command... it hurts being a noob to Laravel lol... thanks for your help man.

Answer (score -1):

The first is to understand whats the error code is saying, according to this 404 Not Found client error response code indicates that the server can't find the requested resource, first of try to clean this in a way

```
 onDelete(user_id) {
    url = `http://localhost:8000/users/delete/${user_id}`;
    //here make sure url is fine with Id
    axios.delete(url)
        .then((response) => {

        })
    }
```

after this you have to check in the network call, either the request is going fine to the server with id or not. then lastly double check api is expecting the delete call or its expecting the get call with id for deletion, because many backend guys delete records by using get calls. ping me back if still is not fixed.