# How do I call the laravel destroy function through an html form and javascript?

Tags: php, laravel

Controller:

```
public function destroy(Pessoa $pessoa)
{
    $pessoa->delete();
    return redirect("http://localhost:5500/index.html");
}
```

I can use post with

```
 <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pessoas" method="POST">
```

But how can I do it with the delete method?

Comment: duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use DELETE method in route with Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Just add a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />` or in Blade, `@method('delete')`

Comment: @WaseemAlhabash I saw this post, but I'm using laravel as an API. The thing is I want to delete the column through the html, using <form>

Comment: @miken32  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pessoas" method="delete">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />

Comment: This way? It didn't work.

Comment: I made no suggestion to change the form element.

Comment: I also tried to pass an id, but it just showed me the column... :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add `csrf` and `method` via blade

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pessoas" method="post">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
</form>
```

Alternatively, using Javascript [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pessoas", {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

here is complete example:

```
<form action="{{ route('category.destroy', $category->id) }}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('{{ trans('global.areYouSure') }}');" style="display: inline-block;">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete">
```

define into the route:

```
Route::delete('/category/delete/{id}', 'CategoryController@destroy')->name('category.destroy');
```

controller will be look like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
$category = Category::find($id);
$category->delete();

return back()->with('success', 'Item is deleted successfully');
}
```