# The DELETE method is not supported for route demande/delete/remove/4. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel-8

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('/demande/delete/remove/{id}', [StagiaireController::class, 'demande_remove'])->name('demande.remove');
```

**Controller:**

```
        public function demande_remove($id)
        {
                $demande = Demande::findOrFail($id);
   
                if ($demande) {
                   
                    $demande->stagiaires()->delete();

                    $demande->documents()->delete();
        
                    $demande->delete();
        
        
                    return redirect()->route('demande.list')->with('success', 'Demande, stagiaires et documents associés supprimés avec succès.');
                }
        
        }
```

**view:**

```
<form action="{{ route('demande.remove', $demande->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
            <a href="{{ route('demande.detail',$demande->id )}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Annuler</a>
        </form>
```

I wanted to delete all the elements associated with a demand ,I tried to debug but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Here's an example of the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing Maybe you need to put @method before @csrf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use DELETE method in route with Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113969/use-delete-method-in-route-with-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Did you cache your routes? Try `php artisan route:clear`. Still the same error? remove `@method('DELETE')` just to check

Comment: Why your route is this? ```Route::delete('/demande/delete/remove/{id}', [StagiaireController::class, 'demande_remove'])->name('demande.remove');``` It seems this gonna work